# pythonnet on Sagemaker cannot import clr

Tags: mono, amazon-sagemaker, python.net

I cannot import clr from SageMaker with this error.
What kind of tweaks make this successful ?

From Sagemaker console :

```
source activate python3    
conda install pythonnet
```

This seems to finely install pythonnet without error.

In python code :

```
import clr
```

This produce this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_clr.py", line 1, in <module>
    import clr
ImportError: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sys' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/../lib/libmono-native.so assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.LChflagsCanSetHiddenFlag()
  at Interop+Sys..cctor () [0x00000] in <aa5dff9b31c64fce86559bbbf6cd364f>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Interop.GetRandomBytes (System.Byte* buffer, System.Int32 length) [0x00000] in <aa5dff9b31c64fce86559bbbf6cd364f>:0 
  at System.Guid.FastNewGuidArray () [0x00020] in <aa5dff9b31c64fce86559bbbf6cd364f>:0 
  at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder..ctor (System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder assb, System.String name, System.String fullyqname, System.Boolean emitSymbolInfo, System.Boolean transient) [0x00035] in <aa5dff9b31c64fce86559bbbf6cd364f>:0 
  at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule (System.String name, System.String fileName, System.Boolean emitSymbolInfo, System.Boolean transient) [0x0005b] in <aa5dff9b31c64fce86559bbbf6cd364f>:0 
  at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule (System.String name) [0x00000] in <aa5dff9b31c64fce86559bbbf6cd364f>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.CodeGenerator..ctor () [0x0002b] in <0e10ac2b10a44c1baa160aa337220b6a>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.DelegateManager..ctor () [0x00061] in <0e10ac2b10a44c1baa160aa337220b6a>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] args, System.Boolean setSysArgv, System.Boolean initSigs) [0x0000a] in <0e10ac2b10a44c1baa160aa337220b6a>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize (System.Boolean setSysArgv, System.Boolean initSigs) [0x00005] in <0e10ac2b10a44c1baa160aa337220b6a>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.InitExt () [0x00000] in <0e10ac2b10a44c1baa160aa337220b6a>:0
```

Environment :

- Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
- Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.90 (tarball Fri Mar  5 04:37:13 UTC 2021)
- Python 3.6.13
- conda 4.8.4
- pythonnet 2.4.0

Similar symptoms :

[System.DllNotFoundException when trying to import clr, despite referenced assembly existing #1034](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1034) : I confirmed libmono-native.so library there in the right directory.